# Using Jespa WIndow Authentication

Tags: java, security

Who know how to configure the web.xml jespa services account name and bindstr value?

Answer (score 0):

`jespa.service.acctname` should be set to the name of the account setup to connect to Active Directory as a computer account, and `jespa.bindstr` should be the host name of your AD server.  Note that you also need to make sure you set a unique `localhost.netbios.name` value for each instance running jespa which will use the same account to connect to AD (we use a combination of application & hostname).

See the Jespa operator manual available [here](http://www.ioplex.com/support.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you just go through the Installation section in the Jespa Operator's Manual it describes exactly how to create the Computer account and get the example webapp working. In fact if you use the "SetupWizard" it will pick values for you to just copy and paste into the HttpSecurityService properties file.

Note that if you if you want proper failover it is important to set the jespa.bindstr property to the fully qualified DNS domain name of the domain and not a specific hostname. With a domain name Jespa will use DNS SRV lookups to locate a suitable domain controller. And for optimal performance you should set the jespa.dns.site property (correctly!) as well so that Jespa will only use DCs in your server's geo-location (for details see the Active Directory Sites and Services section in the Jespa Operator's Manual).